# What is the term for an RNN that is a completely connected directed graph?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, terminology

There seems to be a severe problem with the taxonomy of neural network topologies.  What I'd like to know is the term I should use to search for the most general topology:  completely connected directed cyclic graph (henceforth CCDCGRNN).  This is because all other topologies degenerate by constraint from CCDCGRNN.  This includes topologies that are often confused with CCDCGRNN such as Elfman and Jordan networks* and more legitimately-so than, say LSTMs.

I know there are  [*claims* such as this question at stats.stackexchange.com (including cites)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210111/recurrent-neural-network-rnn-topology-why-always-fully-connected) that unqualified "RNN" refers to CCDCGRNN but this is not true if one looks a little deeper. Examples include not only [the Wikipedia article on "RNN" (who trusts WP anyway, right?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), but a ["mostly complete" catalog of neural network topologies](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-mostly-complete-chart-of-neural-networks-explained-3fb6f2367464).

There must have been, at some point in the ancient past, research into the methods by which one can, in a principled manner, degenerate the CCDCGRNs or at least why it isn't worth studying in its own right.

*RNNs containing feed-through time delays are a degenerate case of CCDCGRNNs where a time delay of N out of a node is accomplished by allocating N neurons constrained to have only one input with weight of 1 (and a linear transfer function with slope 1).